# Not able load packages after downloading

Tags: r, package, knitr

I have been using R on and off but recently when I tried to use it again and download packages (e.g. knitr), it wouldn't download the packages at all and it keeps saying it's in the Temp Folder. However, when I followed the path location for the package, it only showed up as a GZ file instead of a zip file.. I then cannot load the package at all.

I have been looking around online but nothing seems to work so far..

I'm using RStudio 2023.03.0+386 "Cherry Blossom" Release (3c53477afb13ab959aeb5b34df1f10c237b256c3, 2023-03-09) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.0+386 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36

I tried to download new R versions, reboot the computer, download packages over again. I also tried to manually download the packages as zip file and put it in the permanent library folder (didn't work). I suspected there could have been a locked folder in the Temp folder preventing the packages from being downloaded, so I tried to look for that but there wasn't any.

Comment: "However, when I followed the path location for the package, it only showed up as a GZ file instead of a zip file." I'm not certain I'm following. You need to install the package (once) before loading it into R. The GZ file is what you'd use to install it, but you also don't need to. You can just run `install.packages("knitr")`.

Comment: Note that `install.packages` is something you should run outside of your knitr document. If you want to use a package in your document you just call `library()` with the name of the package you want to use. It would be easier to help if you should some of the actual code and output you are running.

Comment: Do you have admin rights on the computer you are using? I have seen situations where packages won't install on Windows unless R is started with "run as Administrator".

Comment: This is what I tried and got:
> install.packages("knitr")
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: Installing package into ‘C:/Users/marge/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘xfun’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
      binary source needs_compilation
xfun    0.30   0.38              TRUE
knitr   1.38   1.42             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/xfun_0.30.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 398028 bytes (388 KB)
downloaded 388 KB

Comment: package ‘xfun’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\marge\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaiR3Uo\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘knitr’

Comment: trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/knitr_1.42.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 893585 bytes (872 KB)
downloaded 872 KB

* installing *source* package 'knitr' ...
** package 'knitr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading

Comment: Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace 'xfun' 0.30 is being loaded, but >= 0.34 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'knitr'
* removing 'C:/Users/marge/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/knitr'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘knitr’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘C:\Users\marge\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaiR3Uo\downloaded_packages’

> library(knitr)
Error in library(knitr) : there is no package called ‘knitr’